# Ubuntu doesn’t work when I start my Mac

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, kernel, startup, mac

I have this iussue. I have a dual boot installed on my iMac (MacOs-Ubuntu 18.0.4) yesterday I shut down my computer from the plug for an error.
Today when I try to start my Mac from Ubuntu it doesn’t require any password and let me see the desktop without icons and Without any possibility to interact with buttons on the top-panel. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Mmore details will help.

Comment: Just this. When I start up my computer it doesn’t require any password. It just show desktop without any icon and without I can do anything. Just move the cursor.